# Automated URL to PDF Save VBA

Tags: excel, vba, google-chrome, pdf-generation

Can anyone help modify this script so that it will save webpages that require login credentials and authentication? Perhaps, embedding a username and password, keeping Chrome's cookie session active, or automatically appending the hyperlinks with login information. The script will only convert non-authenticated hyperlinks put in the URL file.

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

' File paths
Const URLFile = "C:\Users\krgil\Desktop\vba script\urls.txt"  ' Path to the text file containing URLs
Const ChromePath = "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" ' Path to Chrome executable
Const SaveFolder = "C:\Users\krgil\Desktop\testing script" ' Path to the folder where PDF files will be saved

' Read URLs from the text file
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(URLFile, 1)
arrURLs = Split(objFile.ReadAll, vbCrLf)
objFile.Close

' Open Chrome in headless mode
objShell.Run Chr(34) & ChromePath & Chr(34) & " --headless --disable-gpu", 0

' Loop through each URL and save as PDF
For Each strURL in arrURLs
    ' Create a unique filename for each URL
    strFileName = SaveFolder & "page_" & Replace(Replace(strURL, "://", "_"), "/", "_") & ".pdf"

    ' Open the URL in Chrome and print as PDF
    objShell.Run Chr(34) & ChromePath & Chr(34) & " --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf=""" & strFileName & """ """ & strURL & """", 0

    ' Wait for Chrome to finish saving the PDF
    WScript.Sleep 5000
Next

' Close Chrome
objShell.Run "taskkill /F /IM chrome.exe", 0, True

MsgBox "PDF conversion completed!"

Set objShell = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing
```

I've tried resolving with other extensions, methods, and approaches but to no avail.